# Raspberry Pi 3 等のARMで動作するAndroid Nougatを自分でビルドしたい。

Tags: android

私は、Raspberry Pi 3 で動作するAndroid Nougatを自分でビルドしたいと思っています。
Androidは、オープンソースのはずですが、検索しても、実践している人があまりいなかった上、よく分かりませんでした。
ARM64向けのAndroidのイメージをビルドする方法を教えてください!!
PCは、CPUがintel 64ビットで、OSはUbuntu Bionicです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

公式サイトにビルド方法が詳しく書かれているので、まずはこれに従ってください: https://source.android.com/setup/

その上で何か個別の手順で具体的な問題があれば、またご質問くださればと思います。